# Retrieving only custom post types with two required terms (from diferente custom taxonomies each)?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I created one custom post type and two custom taxonomies.

```
register_post_type('blocks',array(
       'labels' => array(
         'name' => __( 'Blocks' ),
         'singular_name' => __( 'Block' ),
         'add_new_item' => 'Add New Block',
         'edit_item' => 'Edit Block',
         'new_item' => 'New Block',
         'search_items' => 'Search Block',
         'not_found' => 'No Block found',
         'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Blocks found in trash',
       ),
       'public' => true,
       'hierarchical' => false,
       'taxonomies' => array( 'section'),
       'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','custom-fields'),
       'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'blocks','with_front'=>false),
     ));

    register_taxonomy('location','blocks',array(
       'hierarchical' => true,
       'labels' => array(
         'name' => __( 'Location' ),
         'singular_name' => __( 'Location' ),
         'add_new_item' => 'Add New Location',
         'edit_item' => 'Edit Location',
         'new_item' => 'New Location',
         'search_items' => 'Search Location',
         'not_found' => 'No Locations found',
         'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Locations found in trash',
         'all_items' => __( 'All Sections' ),
       ),
       'query_var' => true,
       'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'location' ),
       ));
     register_taxonomy('section','blocks',array(
       'hierarchical' => true,
       'labels' => array(
         'name' => __( 'Section' ),
         'singular_name' => __( 'Section' ),
         'add_new_item' => 'Add New Section',
         'edit_item' => 'Edit Section',
         'new_item' => 'New Section',
         'search_items' => 'Search Section',
         'not_found' => 'No Sections found',
         'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Sections found in trash',
         'all_items' => __( 'All Sections' ),
       ),
       'query_var' => true,
       'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'section' ),
       ));
```

I'm using the following to retrieve them:

```
<?php // Create and run custom loop
    $custom_posts = new WP_Query();
    $custom_posts->query('post_type=blocks&location=Front Page&section=Profile');
    while ($custom_posts->have_posts()) : $custom_posts->the_post();
?>
    <div class="block-1">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>


    <?php // Create and run custom loop
        $custom_posts = new WP_Query();
        $custom_posts->query('post_type=blocks&location=Front Page&section=Theme Left');
        while ($custom_posts->have_posts()) : $custom_posts->the_post();
    ?>
        <div class="float-left">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

The problem is that any posts that has the custom taxonomy Location = Front Page appear in the first custom loop.

It shouldn't. The first custom loop should ONLY retrieve custom posts which has these two terms (from different taxonomies): Location = Front Page and Section = Profile.

(If only one term is missing the posts shouldn't be retrieved)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please mark your answer as solution (this does work).

Answer (score 2):

Well, downloading Wordpress 3.1 RC3 solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

yes, wordpress 3.1 addresses exactly this requirement with "advanced taxonomy queries".

otto's done a great in-depth explanation at http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-1-advanced-taxonomy-queries/